# Should I place an article before "20/20 vision"?

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article, uncountable-nouns

> Having **(a)** 20/20 vision is the desirable condition of the eye.
>
> If you have **(a)** 20/20 vision you don't need glasses.
>
> **(A)** 20/20 vision is required for certain job positions.

Is the article "a" necessary or correct in these sentences?

I wanted to ask this question because sometimes I find the article "a" before "20/20 vision" and other times not. I'd like to know why.

You can find several examples on this [ngram search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%2020/20%20vision%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02_t5HkW15h9ezqtof7Aaf01KBV7A:1612884711046&ei=56oiYK-iAsfukgXsoImoAQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjvsY_ij93uAhVHt6QKHWxQAhUQ8NMDCIwB&biw=1366&bih=663&dpr=1), although the focus of this question is about the specific examples above.

> "In that state you must have a 20/20 vision in one eye"
>
> "A 20/20 vision is normal vision for distance"
>
> "However, it is of interest that 35.9 per cent of those with a 20/20
> vision and 40 per cent of those with a 20/30 vision complained of eye
> symptoms"
>
> "...whereas commercial pilots are accepted if they have a 20/20 vision
> with correction"
>
> " She has a 20/20 vision in the right eye by the use of a Schnelling's
> chart"
>
> "First, the student, because he has a 20/20 vision as indicated by
> the test above, believes his vision is “normal”"
>
> "Their report to applicant stated J. B. Pierce had a 20/40 vision of
> his right eye without glasses and a 20/20 vision of the same eye with
> glasses"

Comment: The first link in your search is "( a ) 20/20 vision proves there is no myopia but there may be some hyperopia concealed by accommodation . ( b ) ..." That is not an article, that's a list. Another example is "... is using a 20 / 20 Vision System" where the article is being used for "system" and not "vision". NGrams have to be used very carefully when looking for usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text from your [first link](https://rexhamiltonmd.com/visual-acuity-is-20-20-perfect-vision/) is full of errors. I don't know who wrote this but I hope that their surgical skills are better than their writing skills.

The [second link](http:///www.zennioptical.com/blog/visual-acuity-the-true-meaning-of-20-20-vision/) uses normal English grammar.

---

**Answer**

The first text is wrong.  Do **not**  rely on any English from that site.

Use 20/20 without the article.

---

**Grammatical reason for not having an article**

The word "vision" when referring to the ability to see is an uncountable noun. Uncountable nouns do not have articles.

Thus we say, "John has good vision" or "Mary has poor vision" or "Duncan was blind from birth and so lacks vision entirely"

> vi•sion /ˈvɪʒən/   n.  Physiology[**uncountable**]the act or power of
> sensing with the eyes; sight.
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/vision

---

P.S. Here is one of the many errors:

> Perhaps, the doctor told you to have 20/20 vision

A doctor can tell you "that you have" 20/20 vision. They cannot tell you "to have" 20/20 vision!!!

I won't say that the site is a scam. I couldn't possibly know or comment on that - I have no evidence either way. I do however know that scam sites often use incorrect English.

Comment: That site is not the only place you can find "a 20/20 vision". Here's an ngram search https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+20/20+vision%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02_t5HkW15h9ezqtof7Aaf01KBV7A:1612884711046&ei=56oiYK-iAsfukgXsoImoAQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjvsY_ij93uAhVHt6QKHWxQAhUQ8NMDCIwB&biw=1366&bih=663&dpr=1.

Comment: @Fra Just because you can find something on the Internet doesn't mean it is correct. Why do you think those links are any more valid than the first example you chose?

Comment: There is something odd about those links. If you click on them, most say, ***No results in this book for "a 20/20 vision" Search other books***

Comment: @ColleenV Because they are quite a few. Had it been one or two, I wouldn't have had many doubts.

Comment: @Fra As I mentioned above, most of those examples are not "a 20/20 vision" - they're a completely different construction. You have to look at the actual results returned by NGrams, not the number of results.

Comment: (@ColleenV) @chasly - supports Monica I also would like to know the grammatical reason you suggested to not put the article.

Comment: @ColleenV  I added more relevant examples. I'm sorry if I seem distrustful but could they be all wrong?

Comment: @Fra - I will add the grammatical reason to my answer.

Comment: "Vision" as in "a vision for the future" is countable.  I could imagine someone, even a native speaker, using the phrase "a 20/20 vision for the future," but I'd consider that to be a mixed metaphor and not a great choice of words.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee - I agree but in my answer, I excluded other meanings.

Comment: @Fra - You added more examples but you didn't include a link for each one (as Colleen did in her edit). Without being able to examine each sentence in context, it will be difficult for anyone to explain why a sentence is written the way that it is written. (Colleen already explained one, where the "a" is part of an alphabetized list, not an article.)

Comment: @J.R. - You appear to have edited the question since I answered it. I'm not going to go through the revision history.  I'm sure that Colleen can speak for themselves and is at perfect liberty to submit an answer. You may also answer if you think I've got it wrong.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I've upvoted your answer, so the discussion about the examples isn't really about the correctness of your answer. I added examples from the OPs comments under the question in an edit and then flagged the comment as "no longer needed". The links I added are the "first" and "second" links you refer to in your answer. Then the edit was rolled back and subsequently edited with different examples without links to judge the source of the examples. Your answer is out of sync with the question, which may be a bit confusing to future readers.

Comment: @chasly - I merely edited the [spacing around the punctuation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/274834/revisions); I didn't change the question.